# cURL with PHP keeps returning false or null

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use the Onfleet REST API with cURL using php

```
$url = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/auth/test";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

However I keep getting a false or null result. I tried the same thing using cURL with command lines and it's working perfectly fine, so my API key is not to blame

Comment: please use curl_error($ch) and curl_getinfo($ch) to get an error and update the question

Comment: Thanks, I just solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using curl_error($ch) I found out that my SSL certificate was the problem (working on a local environment)

I simply set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and everything works fine now